# Filter dataframe based on condition before groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

Suppose I have a dataframe like this

[image]

Create sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'gender': np.random.choice(['m', 'f'], size=100),
    'vaccinated': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100),
    'got sick': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and I want to see, by gender, what proportion of vaccinated people got sick.

I've tries something like this:

```
df.groupby('gender').agg(lambda group: sum(group['vaccinated']==1 & group['sick']==1)
                                          /sum(group['sick']==1))
```

but this doesn't work because `agg` works on the series level. Same applies for `transform`. `apply` doesn't work either, but I'm not as clear why or how `apply` functions on groupby objects.

Any ideas how to accomplish this with a single line of code?

Comment: In this case you are niot grouping  by two columns you only have one single grouped columns

Comment: In the future, please strongly consider using `bool` dtype for binary (aka Boolean) data ("1/0" data) instead of integers. It makes your code simpler *and* faster *and* uses less memory *and* it's more semantically meaningful. There's absolutely no reason to use `int`s instead of `bool` in Pandas.

Comment: Also, your code as-written would not work. The `&` operator binds more tightly than `==`, so the code `x == 1 & y == 1` is parsed as `x == (1 & y) == 1` which is definitely not what you want. You need parentheses to establish the correct parsing order: `(x == 1) & (y == 1)`. This of course would be a non-issue using bool dtype, because you could just write `x & y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first filter for the vaccinated people and then group by gender and calculate the proportion of people that got sick..

```
df[df.vaccinated == 1].groupby("gender").agg({"got sick":"mean"})
```

Output:

```
        got sick
gender          
f       0.548387
m       0.535714
```

In this case the proportion is calculated based on a sample data that I've created

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for `GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) state that the function is applied "group-wise". This means that the function is called on each group separately *as a data frame*.

That is, `df.groupby(c).apply(f)` is conceptually equivalent to:

```py
results = {}
for val in df[c]:
    group = df.loc[df[c] == val]
    result = f(group)
    results[val] = result
pd.concat(results)
```

We can use this understanding to apply your custom aggregation function, using a top-level `def` just to make the code easier to read:

```py
def calc_vax_sick_frac(group):
    vaccinated = group['vaccinated'] == 1
    sick = group['sick'] == 1
    return (vaccinated & sick).sum() / sick.sum()

(
    df
    .groupby('gender')
    .apply(calc_vax_sick_frac)
)
```